# I cannot drag an instance specification from the browser to a BDD in rational rhapsody 8.0.1

Tags: uml, rhapsody, sysml

I am able to create an instance specification (with slots) in the browser in rhapsody 8.0.1 in a Sysml project, however I am not able to drag it to any diagram and I have no idea why. Any solution? Thank you.

Comment: You should tag this with "rhapsody".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the software itself, I installed the new version of Rhapsody 8.3.1 and the problem is gone.